# Django: How to directly load the data from the method in the view to Html page without any request

Tags: python, html, django

I have a method which sends the data to HTML page direclt without any request.

views.py

```
def SendSentence():
    sentence = "Hello World"
    html = render_to_string('Display.html', Context({'Sentence': sentence}))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Display.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
{% csrf_token %}
The data is ...{{ Sentence }}...
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly let me know Is this possible? or let me know how to get the response directly from the view.py to a html page when it is called

Comment: without any request? you'll make a url request anyway right?

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/views/):

> A view function, or view for short, is simply a Python function that takes a Web request and returns a Web response.

request is required argument for a view function. So by definition, you cannot use `SendSentence()` as a view.

You can define `SendSentence()` as:

```
def SendSentence(request):
    # do not do anything with request
    sentence = "Hello World"
    html = render_to_string('Display.html', Context({'Sentence': sentence}))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

However, the standard way to render a template is:

```
def SendSentence(request):
    sentence = "Hello World"
    return render(request, 'Display.html', dict(Sentence=sentence))
```

Comment: yes...I got that if we send a request to the view then we will get the respond back. But in my case I'm not sending the request.I need to send the values directly from view to html page. whether is it possible to send the data from view to the html page without any request to it?